# Change device - Reassign static IP

Tags: ip, network-discovery

I have a setup for a workstation consisting of a PC, monitor and a networked laser printer. The PC uses DHCP to get an IP, but the network printer must be assigned a static IP due to a requirement with the software from which it is accessed.

The question now is, is there a way that if the network printer had to be switched with a new network printer, that the new network printer would be able to get the same static IP as the previous network printer without the person who is switching having to do anything more than plug in the power and ethernet cable? This could be either through network settings or programmatically.

Comment: Uh, no. By definition, *static* means you configured it to have that address.

Comment: That is not entirely true because what if you were, based on the MAC address, programmatically assign a static ip to the device? Note: I forgot about MAC addresses on devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need to know the MAC address of the newly plugged in printer beforehand. Then you could reserve a specific IP address for that MAC address through DHCP Reservation.

Note that that's not the same as a **static IP** (thanks @Ricky Beam for pointing that out). The device would always receive the **same IP** though.

Comment: That's a *DHCP Reservation*, not a **static IP**.

Comment: Fair enough. I acknowledge that that's not the same. I suppose that's what the Question Creator is looking for, though.

Comment: Yes, that is then not static IP, but it is the kind of answer I am looking for.